# Pandas extract multiple column values based on iloc and store in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe like as below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'region': ['ASEAN','ANZ','INDIA','KOREA'],
'first_contact':['user1','user2','user3','user4'],'first_contact_email':['user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com','user3@gmail.com','user4@gmail.com'],
'second_contact':['user11','user21','user31','user41'],'second_contact_email':['user11@gmail.com','user21@gmail.com','user31@gmail.com','user41@gmail.com'],
'third_contact':['user111','user211','user311','user411'],'third_contact_email':['user111@gmail.com','user211@gmail.com','user311@gmail.com','user411@gmail.com'],
'fourth_contact':['user1111','user2111','user3111','user4111'],'fourth_contact_email':['user1111@gmail.com','user2111@gmail.com','user3111@gmail.com','user4111@gmail.com'],
'fifth_contact':['user11111','user21111','user31111','user41111'],'fifth_contact_email':['user11111@gmail.com','user21111@gmail.com',np.nan,np.nan],
'sixth_contact':['user111111','user211111','user311111','user411111'],'sixth_contact_email':['user111111@gmail.com','user211111@gmail.com',np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) iterate through each row

b) get all email_id for that row

c) append it to a list

So, I tried the below

region_list = ['ASEAN','INDIA','KOREA','ANZ']

```
for region in region_list:
   email_list=[]
   temp_email_df = df1[df1['Region']==region]
   email_list.append(temp_email_df.iloc[0,2:,2].to_string(header=False, index=False))
   print(email_list)
   --send email code follows here
```

for each region, I would like to get their list of email ids and use them to send an email.

But now the issue is in extracting all the emails.

How can I do to extract email-ids from all the email columns using iloc or positions etc

I expect my output to print email_list for each region

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` method to filter the regions based on the list you have, then filter the columns that has `email` in the name, finally `stack` it which will essentially remove `NaN` values, then call `to_list()` to create list out of it:

```py
>>> df1[df1['region'].isin(region_list)].filter(like='email').stack().to_list()

['user1@gmail.com', 'user11@gmail.com', 'user111@gmail.com', 'user1111@gmail.com', 'user11111@gmail.com', 'user111111@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com', 'user21@gmail.com', 'user211@gmail.com', 'user2111@gmail.com', 'user21111@gmail.com', 'user211111@gmail.com', 'user3@gmail.com', 'user31@gmail.com', 'user311@gmail.com', 'user3111@gmail.com', 'user4@gmail.com', 'user41@gmail.com', 'user411@gmail.com', 'user4111@gmail.com']
```

But if you need to get the email list by region, you can group the dataframe by `regions` after filtering the regions of interest then follow the rest of logic

```py
(df1[df1['region'].isin(region_list)]
 .set_index('region')
 .filter(like='email')
 .groupby(level=0)
 .apply(lambda x: x.stack().tolist())
 .reset_index())

  region                                                  0
0    ANZ  [user2@gmail.com, user21@gmail.com, user211@gm...
1  ASEAN  [user1@gmail.com, user11@gmail.com, user111@gm...
2  INDIA  [user3@gmail.com, user31@gmail.com, user311@gm...
3  KOREA  [user4@gmail.com, user41@gmail.com, user411@gm...
```

Comment: nice. if you don't mind, can also show me with index or iloc on how can we extract all email ids?

Comment: Yes, I need to filter based on each region. So, there should be 4 output lines printed with each line showing email ids for each region

Comment: @TheGreat see the updated answer for emails grouped by region.

Comment: @TheGreat talking about solution using `iloc`, it will be really slow because of manual iteration using a loop, instead you should use above proposed vectorized way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but for the purpose of learning would you be interested to share that approach as well? I will follow vectorized approach but just to know how to extract columns, I would like to know

Comment: using `iloc` for columns?

Comment: yes iloc for columns

Comment: You can replace `.filter(like='email')` by `.iloc[:, :]` it will select all rows for all columns since you need all the columns for email

Comment: oh without specifying any position number, how will it get all email id columns (and get their values)?

Comment: I will only need columns that contain email ids (and not all columns)

Comment: @ThePyGuy: nice solution, I think performance would improve still by using `.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)` instead of `.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.stack().tolist())`.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows.

- Use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to unpivot `df1` from wide to long format for all `columns` that contain the substring "email".
- Use [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `value` (column that now contains all "emails") as the subset to get rid of `NaN` values.
- Finally, use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group "emails" per region, and then `apply(list)` to group the individual values in a list.
- Result will be a `pd.Series` with the regions as `index`. So, to access the specific lists, you use, e.g., `emails['ANZ']`, and then first email: `emails['ANZ'][0]` (i.e. "user2@gmail.com").

```
emails = df1.melt(id_vars='region', 
         value_vars=[col for col in df1.columns if 'email' in col]
         ).dropna(subset='value').groupby('region')['value'].apply(list)

print(emails)
region
ANZ      [user2@gmail.com, user21@gmail.com, user211@gm...
ASEAN    [user1@gmail.com, user11@gmail.com, user111@gm...
INDIA    [user3@gmail.com, user31@gmail.com, user311@gm...
KOREA    [user4@gmail.com, user41@gmail.com, user411@gm...
Name: value, dtype: object

# e.g. for `ANZ`:
print(emails['ANZ'])

['user2@gmail.com', 'user21@gmail.com', 'user211@gmail.com', 
 'user2111@gmail.com', 'user21111@gmail.com', 'user211111@gmail.com']
```

Comment: nice, can show me also on how can we extract using index or iloc like how I have done (for one column). Similarly, how can we do for multiple columns using iloc positions etc?

Comment: `melt` is really slow when you have many columns, plus it will require larger memory space as well since individual values will be staying at row level.